# jcarouselAutoscroll with connected-carousels

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

For my functionality. I have to set up autoscrolling for connected carousels example http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/connected-carousels/

I am new to jquery and trying to achieve this using autoscrolling plugin which is available 
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/

Please let me in step by step guidance on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you may check documentation guide :

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/ (here is github example with source code)

[Step by stpe jcarousel](http://www.script-tutorials.com/content-slider-with-jcarousel/)

Here is example.

[How to make step carousel wrap around and then stop on slide #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589477/how-to-make-step-carousel-wrap-around-and-then-stop-on-slide-1)

What I did was:

1 Include jcaroul js in main html page.

2 Then on particular div, we count images and then assign jcarousel class like

```
if (CommentDiv == 'div_Image' && imageCount > 0) {
            context = $('#' + CommentDiv);
            contextDiv = 'fldlb_form';
            $('#lb_imageScrollerDIV', context).remove();
            $('#imgslider', context).html('<div id="lb_imageScrollerDIV" class="jcarousel-skin-tango" style="margin:0 0 0 0" ></div>');
        }
```